# Sencha Touch Production Build Issue with IE10 and Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, extjs, internet-explorer-10, production

I am experiencing an issue with production build version of the Sencha Touch based application not being able to apply styles properly in IE10 and Chrome.

Steps to reproduce:

Main.js

```
Ext.define('Lab.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'main',
requires: [

],
config: {
tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

items: [

{
xtype: 'panel',
cls: 'MyFirstLogo',
itemId: 'firstLogo'
} ]
}
});
```

SCSS file - app.scss

```
.MyFirstLogo{
height: auto !important;
min-height: 100px;
min-width: 404px;
padding: 0px;
background-image:url(../../resources/images/test1.jpeg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: left;
}
```

1. Make sure the background image URL is like this in resources/sass/app.scss - `../../resources/images/test1.jpeg`.
2. Run "sencha app build production" in project root (Lab/)
3. Access the application in IE10 64bit (Win 7) : `http://localhost/lab/build/production/Lab/`
4. Images are not shown at all in IE10. However, when trying this in Chrome it works well. Chrome somehow is able to convert the `../../resources/images/test1.jpeg` to `http://localhost/lab/build/production/Lab/resources/images/test1.jpeg` but IE10 doesn't do it and fails to show the image. This way it also works in my local development environment as it goes with my project structure.
5. In order to make it work in IE10, I have changed the image URL from `../../resources/images/test1.jpeg` to `resources/images/test1.jpeg` (This actually makes sense as resources/ directory is in the project root) in resources/sass/app.scss and rebuild it for production. In this case image starts to appear in IE10 but now when I use Chrome - Image does't show up and Chrome is trying to retrieve the image from this URL which in not right: `http://localhost/lab/build/production/Lab/resources/css/resources/images/test1.jpeg`, and it fails. This way it DOES NOT also work in my local development environment.
6. This issue happens for other resources as well like "fonts".

Could you please help me understand what's going on here with Sencha's Production Build version not working in both IE10 and Chrome at the same time? Is this this bug with Sencha Touch or Chrome or I am missing something here?

Comment: What does IE10 convert the paths to? (Can use some kind of network analyzer, Wireshark etc.).

Comment: When using `../../resources/images/test1.jpeg` IE10 converts it into `http://localhost/lab/build/resources/images/test1.jpeg`- NOT WORKING (missing 'production' in the path) and when using `resources/images/test1.jpeg` IE10 converts it into `http://localhost/lab/build/production/Lab/resources/images/test2.jpeg`, it Works. I feel what IE10 is doing may be correct but what Chrome is doing with the paths is not correct. Please see the point #5 I mentioned above. What you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out to be the known bug in Sencha Touch as confirmed by the Sencha people. Check this link: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?266275. Thanks @peter and @arthurakay for you help. If I need a workaround or further discussion on this. I will start the discussion again. Thanks guys!

Comment: What we are doing now that we have modified our production microloader for Sencha Touch. Previously it was embedding CSS into index.html but now we have changed it to link the CSS from index.html. This is how it was supposed to be done. That's how it happens in development and testing microloader. Works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you going back so many directories in the relative file path?

Whether you're in development or production, the CSS file lives at:

```
{app_root}/resources/css/app.css
```

Assuming your images are here:

```
{app_root}/resources/images/
```

...then your filepaths should look like this:

```
background-image:url(../images/test1.jpeg);
```

FYI I'm assuming Touch 2.3 and Cmd 4.0.x since you didn't specify.

Comment: Thanks @arthurakay for your reply. I am using Touch 2.3.0 with cmd 4.0.1.30. I have tried your suggestion, problem still persists. Using the relative path - Chrome is able to understand the path and converts into `http://localhost/lab/build/production/Lab/resources/images/test1.jpeg` but IE10 converts it into `http://localhost/lab/build/production/images/test1.jpeg` and IE10 doesn't find it.

Comment: try clearing your localstorage and cache... I wonder if some wires are crossed there.

Comment: Cleared cache, everything, cleared localStorage on both IE10 and Chrome, tried running both the scenarios # 4 and 5. Still seeing the same behaviour. It feels like Chrome is trying to locate the images from `resources/css/` directory but IE10 locates images from project root location.

Answer (score 0):

1. The address you access the application (in any browser) becomes the page base address. In your case it's `http://localhost/lab/build/production/Lab/`
   You can confirm this by printing `alert(document.location.href)`.
   Check the trailing slash, please.
2. Address `../../resources/images/test1.jpeg` then means  `http://localhost/lab/build/production/Lab/../../resources/images/test1.jpeg` and translates to incorrect
   `http://localhost/lab/build/resources/images/test1.jpeg`
3. Modify the relative address to `../resources/images/test1.jpeg` to get
   `http://localhost/lab/build/production/resources/css/resources/images/test1.jpeg`

You can always verify the resulting address by entering it to the browser's address bar.
Both IE and Chrome translate paths correctly as this is their basic task.

Comment: Thanks Peter for your reply. Appreciate the explanation. Unluckily I have tried using different relative paths and nothing works out. I am suspecting the problem with Sencha Touch build process for production (the way index.html file is generated). However when doing the testing build (sencha app build testing) site works fine on Chrome and IE10 both.

Comment: Have you tried `document.location.href` and viewing the page source too?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround to make images/icons visible on both IE10 and Chrome.

Here, CSS property given for any given class containing "background-image" should contain working URL's for both IE10 and Chrome as follows :

`.menuHome {
background:url(resources/icons/menu/Home.png),url(../icons/menu/Home.png) no-repeat center;
}`

Here both URL's are present in the CSS property. So IE10 will fetch image from 1st URL and Chrome will fetch image from 2nd url.